# how to create ticks with temperature symbol - °C - in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a chart with a y axis which represents the temperatures on certain days of a year.  I'd like to get the degrees Celsius into the actual ticks on the y label.  Here's the code I've used so far and the chart below it.

```
plt.ylabel('°C',fontsize = 30)
plt.yticks(np.arange(miny,maxy, step=20))
plt.tick_params(labelsize=20)
```

[image]

Previous answers focused on unicode issues, but I found matplotlib is fine with the °C notation as part of a string.  My issue is how to get it into the ticks on the y axis.

Is there anyway to do this with tick_params?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 9):

Two options:

- (Mis)use a [`matplotlib.ticker.EngFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.EngFormatter)
- use a [`matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter)

In both cases, supply the unit `"°C"`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import EngFormatter, StrMethodFormatter

fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

ax.plot([0,1],[-35,30])
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter(unit=u"°C"))

ax2.plot([0,1],[-35,30])
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter(u"{x:.0f} °C"))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I am not using a subplot, and tried plt.yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter(u"{x:.0f} °C")).  It doesn't recognize the yaxis as an attribute.  How would I make it do that?  Thank you.

Comment: `yaxis` is an attribute of the `axes`. You may get the current axes from pyplot via `plt.gca()`. But consider using the OO style anyways.